# Return words from a list that dosen't contain the same words

Tags: python, string, list

Hey (sorry bad english) so let me explain a little further. i want to make a function that takes in a list. let's say a list with a countries and their capital also added their population. i want to return every country-capital pair that dosen't contain the same letter.
like this:

```
countries = [
    ["China PR", "Beijing", 20693000],
    ["India", "New Delhi", 16787949],
    ["Japan", "Tokyo", 13491000],
    ["Philippines", "Manilla", 12877253],
    ["Russia", "Moscow", 11541000],
    ["Egypt", "Cairo", 10230350]
]
#the output should be:
>>> no_common_letters(countries)
[["Japan", "Tokyo"], ["Egypt", "Cairo"]]
```

because Japan and Tokyo dosen't contain the same letters.
anyone know a sulotion to this? i have tried looking around and all i can find is a program that finds a specified letter and check's if it's in. i want to check every word. i am new to python and trying to learn

Comment: If you convert to all lowercase or uppercase, you could use `set()` to compare the names, like `set('tokyo') == set('japan')`. Learn about sets [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). Learn about `lower()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower

Comment: Test this : cou = 'japan' ; cap = 'tokyo' ; all([letter not in cap for letter in cou]) , then try to build your code around it. You can also work from @RandomDavis  comment, but not with ==, rather looking at the intersection of the 2 sets.

Comment: @RandomDavis i see, but how do i check my whole list with set? can i just do set('countries') == set('countries'), but how do than find the ones and print them out. am very new

Comment: By looping through the list and checking each item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
def no_common_letters(array_of_arrays):
    new_array = []
    for array in array_of_arrays:
        determination = []
        for x in array[0]:
            if x not in array[1]:
                determination.append('1')
            else:
                determination.append('0')
        if '0' not in determination:
            new_array.append(array[0:2])

    return new_array

print(no_common_letters([
    ["China PR", "Beijing", 20693000],
    ["India", "New Delhi", 16787949],
    ["Japan", "Tokyo", 13491000],
    ["Philippines", "Manilla", 12877253],
    ["Russia", "Moscow", 11541000],
    ["Egypt", "Cairo", 10230350]
]))


Returns 
>> [["Japan", "Tokyo"], ["Egypt", "Cairo"]]
```

**OR using SETS**

```
def no_common_letters(array_of_arrays):
  new_array = []
  for array in array_of_arrays:
    set1 = set(array[0])
    set2 = set(array[1])
    if not set1.intersection(set2):
      new_array.append(array[0:2])
  return new_array
print(no_common_letters([
    ["China PR", "Beijing", 20693000],
    ["India", "New Delhi", 16787949],
    ["Japan", "Tokyo", 13491000],
    ["Philippines", "Manilla", 12877253],
    ["Russia", "Moscow", 11541000],
    ["Egypt", "Cairo", 10230350]
]))



Returns 
>> [["Japan", "Tokyo"], ["Egypt", "Cairo"]]
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you, i will do some testing with this code and some other code and it really helps me

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try with `set`

```
for x,y,_ in countries:
  if not set(x.lower()).intersection(y.lower()):
    print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use set intersection method to filter:

```
In [2]: [[i[0], i[1]] for i in countries if not set(i[0].lower()).intersection(set(i[1].lower()))]
Out[2]: [['Japan', 'Tokyo'], ['Egypt', 'Cairo']]
```